# Prevent a particular wi-fi spot from trying to connect automatically

Tags: wifi-hotspot

At my work, there's a "guest" wifi spot and one for employees.  The one for employees connects normally, but the guest one requires a log-in process each time, so obviously I just want to use the former.

This creates a problem, though, because sometimes my phone finds the guest network first, and so to get access I need to go to settings and explicitly tell it to connect to the same one.  Annoying.

I'd like to have my phone auto-connect to networks in general, but not to the guest network.  However, I can't find a setting option for autoconnect broken down by network.  Any ideas.

I'm on a Moto X with Android version: 4.4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just long-tap that network on the list and click "Forget network". Android will only autoconnect to networks it has previously connected to and still remembers.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dan suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/79073/16575), you could simply remove the AP from your list of known networks. Your device then would find it again, no problem – but it would no longer auto-connect to it *until you do so once manually.* And the latter point might be a little troublesome, in case you need that AP "from time to time" – as then you'd also need to remove it manually each time you've used it.

So if the latter is the case, you might wish to take a look at e.g. **[Open WiFi Cleaner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.dje.openwifinetworkremover):**

> Removes open WiFi networks from the saved networks list after disconnecting.
>
> - Notification reminders on connection/disconnection
> - Whitelist of open networks to keep
> - Settings saved using Google Android backup service

With that app in use, and the AP in question *not* whitelisted, it would automatically be removed from your list of known networks whenever you decided to manually connect to it. Simply whitelist other possible open APs you want to auto-connect to, so they would not be affected.

Another app with comparable functionality is **[WiFi AP whitelist](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.timtory.wifiapwhitelistpersonal)**.